# ScrollTo onAfter event not being called

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I am using the [ScrollTo plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com.au/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) by Ariel Flesler.

I can't get the onAfter function to work, if I do this the page scrolls but the alert isn't called.

```
$.scrollTo('#'+id+'_anchor', 500, 'easeInCubic', { 
   onAfter:function(){
      alert('test');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.scrollTo('#'+id+'_anchor', 500, {
   easing : 'easeInCubic',
   onAfter : function(){
      alert('test');
   }
});
```

According to the doco you have two ways to call it:

```
$(...).scrollTo( target, duration, settings );
$(...).scrollTo( target, settings );
```

...but not with the easing as a separate parameter like you had:

```
$(...).scrollTo( target, duration, easing, settings );
```

You need to make the easing one of the properties of the settings object.

Comment: This calls the alert but the page doesn't scroll :(

Comment: Yes, sorry, I realised after posting it that it wasn't right. Oops. Answer updated.

Comment: No worries! You have fixed it :D I was wondering where I was going wrong. Thank you so much! :)